# How can i have the app_list in all views in django admin

Tags: python, django

I am overiding the django admin of the site.
In the defult index page they have the `app_list` variable which contain all the apps and then their models.

But the other views that `app_list` is not available but I want to have that available in all views so that I can have them available on sidebar for clicking

In this file

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/sites.py#L382

They have the code like this

`app_list = list(six.itervalues(app_dict))`

but how can I make that avaialble in change_list pages

Comment: Access the content_type model of django

Comment: how can i do that. IN here https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/views/main.py , i think i need to override the chnageLIst view , but i don't know how can i do that

Comment: Just override it, create admin folder inside templates folder. After that create app_index.html, make sure you extend it {% extends "admin/index.html" %}

Answer (score 4):

I know it's 7 years late but I want to point out since I've been in your situation. If your purpose is to obtain all the apps (list of apps) and its respective models, then you could use `available_apps` instead of `app_list`, as `available_apps` can be accessed in all admin pages (see [site.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/sites.py) code below)

```
def each_context(self, request):
    """
    Return a dictionary of variables to put in the template context for
    *every* page in the admin site.
    For sites running on a subpath, use the SCRIPT_NAME value if site_url
    hasn't been customized.
    """
    script_name = request.META['SCRIPT_NAME']
    site_url = script_name if self.site_url == '/' and script_name else self.site_url
    return {
        'site_title': self.site_title,
        'site_header': self.site_header,
        'site_url': site_url,
        'has_permission': self.has_permission(request),
        'available_apps': self.get_app_list(request), #this one
        'is_popup': False,
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Override app_index.html

```
{% extends "admin/index.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load url from future %}

{% if not is_popup %}
{% block breadcrumbs %}
<div class="breadcrumbs">
<a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">{% trans 'Home' %}</a>
&rsaquo;
{% for app in app_list %}
{% blocktrans with app.name as name %}{{ name }}{% endblocktrans %}
{% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
{% endif %}

{% block sidebar %}{% endblock %}
```